# RuntimeError: Can't determine home directory

Tags: python, xampp

I'm trying to run a PYthon Script on a server using xampp. When trying to import matplotlib I get the following error:

```
[Fri Mar 13 10:46:36.219708 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 15320:tid 2012] [client ::1:54631] AH01215:   File "C:/Users/gfranosc/Downloads/xampp-portable-win32-7.2.1-0-VC15/xampp/htdocs/Python/test.py", line 5, in <module>\r: C:/Users/gfranosc/Downloads/xampp-portable-win32-7.2.1-0-VC15/xampp/htdocs/Python/test.py
[Fri Mar 13 10:46:36.220702 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 15320:tid 2012] [client ::1:54631] AH01215:     from LambWaveModes import *\r: C:/Users/gfranosc/Downloads/xampp-portable-win32-7.2.1-0-VC15/xampp/htdocs/Python/test.py
[Fri Mar 13 10:46:36.220702 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 15320:tid 2012] [client ::1:54631] AH01215:   File "C:\\Users\\gfranosc\\Downloads\\xampp-portable-win32-7.2.1-0-VC15\\xampp\\htdocs\\Python\\LambWaveModes.py", line 13, in <module>\r: C:/Users/gfranosc/Downloads/xampp-portable-win32-7.2.1-0-VC15/xampp/htdocs/Python/test.py
[Fri Mar 13 10:46:36.221697 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 15320:tid 2012] [client ::1:54631] AH01215:     from matplotlib import pyplot as plt\r: C:/Users/gfranosc/Downloads/xampp-portable-win32-7.2.1-0-VC15/xampp/htdocs/Python/test.py
[Fri Mar 13 10:46:36.221697 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 15320:tid 2012] [client ::1:54631] AH01215:   File "C:\\Users\\gfranosc\\Downloads\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\pyplot.py", line 32, in <module>\r: C:/Users/gfranosc/Downloads/xampp-portable-win32-7.2.1-0-VC15/xampp/htdocs/Python/test.py
[Fri Mar 13 10:46:36.221697 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 15320:tid 2012] [client ::1:54631] AH01215:     import matplotlib.colorbar\r: C:/Users/gfranosc/Downloads/xampp-portable-win32-7.2.1-0-VC15/xampp/htdocs/Python/test.py
[Fri Mar 13 10:46:36.222692 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 15320:tid 2012] [client ::1:54631] AH01215:   File "C:\\Users\\gfranosc\\Downloads\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\colorbar.py", line 31, in <module>\r: C:/Users/gfranosc/Downloads/xampp-portable-win32-7.2.1-0-VC15/xampp/htdocs/Python/test.py
[Fri Mar 13 10:46:36.222692 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 15320:tid 2012] [client ::1:54631] AH01215:     import matplotlib.contour as contour\r: C:/Users/gfranosc/Downloads/xampp-portable-win32-7.2.1-0-VC15/xampp/htdocs/Python/test.py
[Fri Mar 13 10:46:36.223688 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 15320:tid 2012] [client ::1:54631] AH01215:   File "C:\\Users\\gfranosc\\Downloads\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\contour.py", line 16, in <module>\r: C:/Users/gfranosc/Downloads/xampp-portable-win32-7.2.1-0-VC15/xampp/htdocs/Python/test.py
[Fri Mar 13 10:46:36.223688 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 15320:tid 2012] [client ::1:54631] AH01215:     import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager\r: C:/Users/gfranosc/Downloads/xampp-portable-win32-7.2.1-0-VC15/xampp/htdocs/Python/test.py
[Fri Mar 13 10:46:36.224683 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 15320:tid 2012] [client ::1:54631] AH01215:   File "C:\\Users\\gfranosc\\Downloads\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\matplotlib\\font_manager.py", line 103, in <module>\r: C:/Users/gfranosc/Downloads/xampp-portable-win32-7.2.1-0-VC15/xampp/htdocs/Python/test.py
[Fri Mar 13 10:46:36.224683 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 15320:tid 2012] [client ::1:54631] AH01215:     os.path.join(str(Path.home()), r'AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Fonts'),\r: C:/Users/gfranosc/Downloads/xampp-portable-win32-7.2.1-0-VC15/xampp/htdocs/Python/test.py
[Fri Mar 13 10:46:36.225680 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 15320:tid 2012] [client ::1:54631] AH01215:   File "C:\\Users\\gfranosc\\Downloads\\Python\\lib\\pathlib.py", line 1079, in home\r: C:/Users/gfranosc/Downloads/xampp-portable-win32-7.2.1-0-VC15/xampp/htdocs/Python/test.py
[Fri Mar 13 10:46:36.225680 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 15320:tid 2012] [client ::1:54631] AH01215:     return cls(cls()._flavour.gethomedir(None))\r: C:/Users/gfranosc/Downloads/xampp-portable-win32-7.2.1-0-VC15/xampp/htdocs/Python/test.py
[Fri Mar 13 10:46:36.225680 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 15320:tid 2012] [client ::1:54631] AH01215:   File "C:\\Users\\gfranosc\\Downloads\\Python\\lib\\pathlib.py", line 264, in gethomedir\r: C:/Users/gfranosc/Downloads/xampp-portable-win32-7.2.1-0-VC15/xampp/htdocs/Python/test.py
[Fri Mar 13 10:46:36.226676 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 15320:tid 2012] [client ::1:54631] AH01215:     raise RuntimeError("Can't determine home directory")\r: C:/Users/gfranosc/Downloads/xampp-portable-win32-7.2.1-0-VC15/xampp/htdocs/Python/test.py
[Fri Mar 13 10:46:36.226676 2020] [cgi:error] [pid 15320:tid 2012] [client ::1:54631] AH01215: RuntimeError: Can't determine home directory\r: C:/Users/gfranosc/Downloads/xampp-portable-win32-7.2.1-0-VC15/xampp/htdocs/Python/test.py
[Fri Mar 13 10:46:36.228667 2020] [authz_core:error] [pid 15320:tid 2012] [client ::1:54631] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/xampp/apache
```

Can someone help me? Do I "just" have to clarify the home directory? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: The problem is that matplotlib is trying to load fonts from your home folder, but the user that xampp is running as doesn't have access to that. It would be better to move the fonts out of your home folder and into a directory that is accessible by xampp/matplotlib

Comment: @WillKeeling After moving them, how do I tell my programm, where these fonts are stored?

Comment: You should be able to tell matplotlib about them. Are you able to post your code for `test.py`?

Comment: #!C:/Users/gfranosc/Downloads/Python/python.exe
import os
from numpy import *
from LambWaveModes import *
print("Content-Type: text/html\n")
LWM(Steifmat=[[[3.5,1.5,0],[1.5,3.5,0],[0,0,1]],[[103.08e9,2.8189e9,0],[2.8189e9,5.6469e9,0],[0,0,3.2727e9]]],rho=[1,1490],layer_thickness=[1,1],name="dataset_med",folder='dataset_1',color=0)
print( os.getcwd() )

Thats the code. The start of LambWaveModes reads:

#!C:/Users/gfranosc/Downloads/Python/python.exe
from S_L_o import *
from math import *
from numpy import *
from copy import *

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

Comment: @WillKeeling How do i format that in a more readable fashion? `code` doesn't work